# Using sprites in a nav tag

Tags: html, css

I'm trying create a html navigation bar that uses sprites for social media icons.

I have my nav bar and individual social media icons working correctly in html like so:

```html
<nav>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="icons/64/facebook_icon.png" onmouseover="this.src='icons/64/facebook_icon_hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='icons/64/facebook_icon.png'" /></a>
  <a href="https://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"><img src="icons/64/twitter_icon.png" onmouseover="this.src='icons/64/twitter_icon_hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='icons/64/twitter_icon.png'" /></a>
  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com" target="_blank"><img src="icons/64/linkedin_icon.png" onmouseover="this.src='icons/64/linkedin_icon_hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='icons/64/linkedin_icon.png'" /></a>
  <a href="https://plus.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="icons/64/googleplus_icon.png" onmouseover="this.src='icons/64/googleplus_icon_hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='icons/64/googleplus_icon.png'" /></a>
</nav>
```

But when I try using my sprite version, it does not work:

```css
#facebook {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background: url("images/sprite/64/sprite_original.png") 0 0;
}
#twitter {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background: url("images/sprite/64/sprite_original.png") -64px 0;
}
#linkedin {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background: url("images/sprite/64/sprite_original.png") -128px 0;
}
#googleplus {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background: url("images/sprite/64/sprite_original.png") -192px 0;
}
#facebook:hover {
  background: url("sprite/64/sprite_original.png") 0 -64px;
}
#twitter:hover {
  background: url("sprite/64/sprite_original.png") -64px -64px;
}
#linkedin:hover {
  background: url("sprite/64/sprite_original.png") -128px -64px;
}
#googleplus:hover {
  background: url("sprite/64/sprite_original.png") -192px -64px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a id="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"></a>
  <a id="twitter" href="https://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"></a>
  <a id="linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com" target="_blank"></a>
  <a id="googleplus" href="https://plus.google.com" target="_blank"></a>
</nav>
```

I don't know where I've gone wrong.  I'm still learning so any help is appreciated.

Note: All icons are 64px by 64px.

[my sprite image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r07z5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `display:inline-block;` or `display: block;` to your elements in css like

```
#facebook,#twitter,#linkedin,#googleplus{
     display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works now.  `Display: block;` organised the icons vertically, `Display: inline-block` organised them horizontally, which is what I was looking for

Comment: @smally So happy to help !